# Proof that if $\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)=a$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to p}g(x)=b$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to p}(f+g)(x) = a + b$

Tags: limits, analysis

I am not even sure where to begin on this proof. It is from Frank Morgan's real analysis chapter 4 exercise 5 (there is a free PDF online for anyone who wants to view the exact question and/or chapter, I will leave a link to it below) https://epdf.pub/real-analysis8237cbd4ad99d427837177cdc98a6b4a97610.html

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=a⇔\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta_1>0:\forall x\in|x-p|<\delta→|f(x)-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

$\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=b⇔\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta_2>0:\forall x\in|x-p|<\delta→|g(x)-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Hence $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}>0:\forall x\in|x-p|<\delta→|(f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)|\leqslant|f(x)-a|+|g(x)-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

This by definition means that $\lim_{x\to p}(f+g)(x)=a+b$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof I found on [this website](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx):

$\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x) = a, \lim\limits_{x \to p}g(x) = b$

By definition, of a limit, there exists a $\delta_1>0$ and a $\delta_2>0$ such that $|f(x)-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $|x-p|<\delta_1$ and $|g(x)-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $|x-p|<\delta_2$

Choose $\delta$ to be the minimum value of $\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$

We need to prove $|f(x)+g(x)-(a+b)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-p|<\delta$

This can be rewritten to $|(f(x)-a)+(g(x)-b)|<\epsilon$

Using the triangle inequality, $|(f(x)-a)+(g(x)-b)|\leq|f(x)-a|+|g(x)-b|$

Since $\delta_1\leq\delta$ and $\delta_2\leq\delta$, we have $|(f(x)-a)+(g(x)-b)|\leq|f(x)-a|+|g(x)-b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

Simplifying this last expression, we have $|(f(x)-a)+(g(x)-b)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-p|<\delta$, so $\lim\limits_{x \to p}(f+g)(x) = a + b$

I hope this helps!